# How to add URL link for \cvitem section

Tags: cv

```
\cvitem{}{YoutubeLink1}{Workflow-YouTube}
\cvitem{}{YoutubeLink2}{Editor-in-Chief}
```

I have a `cvitem` section and I want to give this area a link for the **YoutubeLink1** and **YoutubeLink2**. I have found `\href{url}{text}` but I couldn't combine it together with `href` and `cvitem`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your code or how `\cvitem` is defined (please in the future include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/273733) so that it is easier to help), this works and hyperlinks to the URL in the second argument to `\cvitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\cvitem[3]{#1 \url{#2} #3}

\begin{document}
\cvitem{}{www.google.com}{Workflow-YouTube}
\cvitem{}{www.youtube.com}{Editor-in-Chief}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this isn't what you wanted, please edit your question to include a MWE and what your desired output is.